# How do I view the number of charcters selected in PHPStorm?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

When I highlight some of my code in PHPStorm, I'd like to know how many characters I've selected. Sublime will show you the number of lines selected AND the number of characters selected. Does Storm have this feature?

Answer (score 4):

Number of characters in selection (including whitespaces: tab/space/line end) is displayed in status bar:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, LazyOne! My status bar was not displayed. I see it now.